# BufferedReader dentro de metodo es accedido a pesar de no haber llamado al metodo

Tags: java, while, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo una GUI para un cliente. Este cliente está programado en c++ y es simplemente un programa que envía comandos a un servidor y recibe una respuesta. Esta GUI se conecta con el .exe generado y lo ejecuta para así mandar los comandos.

Pues bien, este cliente se ejecuta con dos argumentos: una IP y un puerto. Para eso tengo dos Text Fields, y un botón de enviar llamado `lanzarPrograma`. Luego, tengo otros dos fields para ingresar apellido y nombre y su boton de enviar llamado `enviarUsuario`. El output de todos lo printeo en un TextArea. Para lanzar el programa uso el método `runExternalProgram` lo cual hace lo que tiene que hacer y printea el output que corresponde en el TextArea. Cuando envío el nombre y el apellido, también printea el output correspondiente. Sin embargo, NO DEBERÍA, pues para enviar ese comando hago uso del método `sendCommand`, el cual, asi como está escrito, retorna una lista de strings vacía siempre. Esa lista deberia luego printearse en el textArea. Al entrar en modo debug, me encuentro con que al enviar dicho comando, el programa entra a `sendCommand` y luego salta a `runExternalProgram` y ejecuta específicamente ese bucle while que tiene dentro, el cual permite printear dentro del TextArea. No entiendo por qué hace eso, si no estoy llamando a ese método. Aun peor, cuando ejecuto otro botón para enviar otro comando distinto, el programa no hace ese salto, y no printea nada. A continuación dejo el codigo.

GUIClass.java

```
package com.mycompany.guicliente;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GUIClass {
private Process externalProcess;


private static final String EXE_PATH = "..\\Cliente.exe";

public void runExternalProgram(javax.swing.JTextArea outputTextArea, String ip, String port) {
    try {
        
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(EXE_PATH, ip, port);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        externalProcess = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(externalProcess.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            appendToOutput(outputTextArea, line);
        }

        int exitCode = externalProcess.waitFor();
        appendToOutput(outputTextArea, "External program exited with code: " + exitCode);

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        appendToOutput(outputTextArea, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public List<String> sendCommands(String command) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            if (externalProcess != null) {
                OutputStream outputStream = externalProcess.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
                outputStream.flush();

            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            output.add("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return output;
    }



public void closeProgram() {
    if (externalProcess != null) {
        externalProcess.destroy();
    }
}

private void appendToOutput(javax.swing.JTextArea outputTextArea, String text) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        outputTextArea.append(text + "\n");
    });
}
public void showOutput(List<String> output, javax.swing.JTextArea outputTextArea) {
    for (String line : output) {
        appendToOutput(outputTextArea, line);
    }
}

}
```

GUI.java (la interfaz en si)

```
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.List;

import com.mycompany.guicliente.GUIClass;

public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public GUI() {
    initComponents();
    enviarUsuario.setEnabled(false);
    apellidoField.setEnabled(false);
    nombreField.setEnabled(false);
    activarMotores.setEnabled(false);
    desactivarMotores.setEnabled(false);
    gui = new GUIClass(); // Initialize the GUI class
}
private static GUIClass gui;

private void mandarComandoYActualizar(String command) {
SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        List<String> output = gui.sendCommands(command);
        gui.showOutput(output, outputTextArea);
        return null;
    }
};
worker.execute();
}
private void lanzarProgramaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    String ip = ipIngresar.getText();
    String port = portIngresar.getText();
    if (ip.isEmpty() || port.isEmpty()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Por favor, ingrese IP y Puerto.");
    return; // Don't proceed if IP or Port is missing
    }            
        enviarUsuario.setEnabled(true);
        apellidoField.setEnabled(true);
        nombreField.setEnabled(true);
        ipIngresar.setEnabled(false);
        portIngresar.setEnabled(false);
        lanzarPrograma.setEnabled(false);

    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            gui.runExternalProgram(outputTextArea, ip, port);
            return null;
        }
    };
worker.execute();
}                                              

private void enviarUsuarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String apellidoInput = apellidoField.getText();
    String nombreInput = nombreField.getText();
    if (apellidoInput.isEmpty() || nombreInput.isEmpty()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Por favor, ingrese apellido y nombre.");
    return; 
    }
    activarMotores.setEnabled(true);
    desactivarMotores.setEnabled(true);
    String params = apellidoInput + " " + nombreInput + "\n";
    mandarComandoYActualizar(params);
  
}                                             

private void activarMotoresActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    desactivarMotores.setSelected(false);
    mandarComandoYActualizar("activarMotores");
}                                              

private void desactivarMotoresActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    activarMotores.setSelected(false);
    mandarComandoYActualizar("desactivarMotores");
}                                                 
private void closeProgramActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    gui.closeProgram();
}

 
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
        gui.closeProgram();
    }));
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```